# Stepping or Iterating through BigDecimal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, increment, loops, bigdecimal

My starting point is basically Ryan Bate's [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/111-advanced-search-form).  I have modified his code to accomodate OR clauses as well as AND.

In the User model there are a couple of attributes named hour_price_high and hour_price_low.   Users will set their hourly rate range such as $45.25/h to $55.50/h. Site visitors will search for registered users in a price range such as $50.00/h to $60.00/h.  This search should return all overlapping users. The respective migration entries for these attributes are:

```
# CreateUser migration
...
t.decimal "hour_price_high", :precision => 6, :scale => 2
t.decimal "hour_price_low",  :precision => 6, :scale => 2
...
```

They are of type BigDecimal and I need to increment through these to search for users:

```
# Search.rb
def low_price_or_conditions
    ["users.hour_price_low IN (?)", price_low..price_high] unless price.blank?
end
def high_price_or_conditions
    ["users.hour_price_high IN (?)", price_low..price_high] unless price.blank?
end
```

When I run this code, I get this error:

```
TypeError:
can't iterate from BigDecimal
```

Any ideas of how to increment through these?  I only need to increment back two decimal places.  Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't convert a Range of [BigDecimal](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/BigDecimal.html) to an array:

```
> a = BigDecimal.new('1')
 => #<BigDecimal:12a082bb0,'0.1E1',9(18)> 
> b = BigDecimal.new('5')
 => #<BigDecimal:12a076ec8,'0.5E1',9(18)> 
> (a..b).to_a
TypeError: can't iterate from BigDecimal
```

From the [fine manual](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Range.html#M000702):

> You can only iterate if the start object of the range supports the succ method

And BigDecimal doesn't have a `succ` method. When you feed this:

```
["users.hour_price_low IN (?)", price_low..price_high]
```

to ActiveRecord as a condition, it probably sees that you've given it a Range and calls `to_a` on it to get something that can be SQL-ified and that's where your error comes from.

I think you want to say this:

```
[ "users.hour_price_low >= :lo AND users.hour_price_low <= :hi", { :lo => price_low, :hi => price_hi } ]
```

Similar issues apply to your `hour_price_high`.

Even if `price_low` and `price_high` were integers you wouldn't want to use `IN`, the range could expand to a rather large list and the database would have to compare each one individually.

Comment: You are awesome. Your >= and <= recommendation led me down the right path.  I needed to use a combination of what you said and BETWEEN.  I needed to add this too: ["users.hour_price_low <= ? AND users.hour_price_high >= ?", price_low, price_high] unless price.blank? ... ["users.hour_price_low/high BETWEEN ? AND ?", price_low, price_high] unless price.blank? All tests are passing! Thanks again!